# Will reverting Windows to an earlier restore point mess up Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm dual booting Windows 7 and Xubuntu and I'm about to reset Windows to a prior date from control panel (no disk). I was wondering if there's anything to be worried about there.

Answer (score 2):

No. Using a system restore point only affects files within Windows.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't think so, but better safe than sorry, you know?